# a app that sends messages present in Android device to firebase

Tags: android, firebase

i have created a app which once tapped on it,it sends call logs ,sms and location info from my Android device to firebase . The problem is i have to tap on the app every time to update the database ,i want to make my app run continuously in background so that on every new sms or call it must update details on the firebase.Any suggestions will be helpful and appreciated

Comment: You can easily do this with the AlarmManager (and set up your own time interval) and combine it with a PendingIntent to trigger an Intent and then do whatever you want to do. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670580/simple-alarmmanager-example-for-firing-an-activity-in-10-minutes

Comment: You should implement a service which will update the data to the firebase continuously in background. see this url for more : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html